# how to have clean url in netbeans for jsp

Tags: url, web, url-rewriting, netbeans-7

i would like to remove numerics, symbols and file extensions in the url using netbeans. I tried the following code in **web.xml** but it aint works

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answers are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/files/urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar and XML file http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/urlrewrite.xml

Add **urlrewrite.xml** into your **web-INF** folder then add jar file into your libraries .Then isert this segment into your **web.xml** which defines the filter mapping

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Consider if your href is `<a href="login.jsp">`. In your urlrewrite.xml you can see the following code

```
<rule>
    <from>/Authentication</from>
    <to >/login.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

The `<to>` represents your native URL you can paste your native url here .

The `<from>` represents the altered URL that will be shown on the browser URL .

After editing the urlrewrite.xml you should include only your altered URL in the href tag i.e after changing the urlrewrite.xml your href should should call tha altered URL

```
<a href="/Authentication">
```

Thats it now URL wil shown with **http:abc.com/Authentication/** instead of **http:abc.com/login.jsp/**